# How do I check if a name is among a list of names in python?

Tags: python

I am writing Oregon trail game and this is the code I have that is causing issues, I don't know why it is having issues. What I want to do is if they enter a name that contains a word that is in a list it will set the variable easter_mode to 1 if they don't then it will set easter_mode to 0. The words that need to be in the list are: (Sturtz, sturtz, Nate, nate)
Thank you

```
#asking name
player_name = input('What is your name:')
while len(player_name) >= 0:
  if len(player_name) > 1:
    print("Weclome" + str(player_name))
    print('Which mode do you want to play?')
    mode_choice = input('(easy) More modes comming soon:')
    break
  if len(player_name) == 1:
    player_name_choice = input(str(player_name)+"? Are you kidding me? Only one letter? You might regreat it (Y/N):")
    if player_name_choice == "y" or player_name_choice == "Y":
      print("Ok Your Choice!!...")
      mode_choice = 'easter'
      break
    if player_name_choice == "n" or player_name_choice == "N":
      player_name = input('What is your name:')
  else:
    print("You do not type anything, try again")
    player_name = input('What is your name:')

#Check Easter Egg Names
easter_names = ["nate sturtz", "Nate Sturtz", "Nate", "nate", "Sturtz", "sturtz"]
if player_name in easter_names:
    easter_mode = 1
else:
    easter_mode = 0
#easter eggs for name

if easter_mode == 1:
  year_set = 2005
  mode_choice = 'easter'
else:
  year_set = input('Enter a year whatever you like:')
  if year_set.isdigit():
    return_num = 0
  else:
    return_num = 1
  while return_num == 1:
    print('Error,please try again!')
    year_set = input('Enter a year whatever you like:')
    if year_set.isdigit():
      return_num = 0
    else:
      return_num = 1
  year_set = int(year_set)
```

When I run the full file I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Oregon.py", line 64, in <module>
    player_name = input('What is your name:')
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'nate' is not defined
```

You can view the full code on Github
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nsturtz/Oregon-Trail/master/Oregon.py

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll get this error in Python 2. In Python 2, `input()` uses the **exact** value as your enter it.

In your example, you're typing `nate` and not `'nate'`. The former value is a variable name (which is undefined in your code, hence the `NameError`), whereas the latter is a string.

In Python 3, `input()` behaves as you assume, and passes a string to your code.

If you are sure that you want to use Python 2, you can replace `input()` with `raw_input()` and it will interpret your input as a string rather than a variable name.

Comment: @Benjamin how do I fix that in the programming? make it like this: easter_names = [nate sturtz, Nate Sturtz, Nate, nate, Sturtz, sturtz]?

Comment: @NateSturtz Just replace the `input` function with `raw_input` and it should be OK.

Comment: @NateSturtz If the computer is *nix, chances are that Python 3 is installed. Try running `python3` from the terminal.

Comment: @Benjamin ok, I will make that change right now and Just to be clear i change 
`player_name = input('What is your name:')` to `player_name = raw_input('What is your name:')` ? This is what you are saying?

Comment: and is there a way I can force python3 even if they do not run the command `python3` ?

Comment: @NateSturtz you can also compile and run Python completely from within your user account, you don't need `sudo` at all. I ***highly*** recommend leaning Py3 first, then going back and learning the differences in 2. If you start w/ 2, you'll pick up some bad habits that you'll have to get rid of when you move to 3.

Comment: @NateSturtz You could add a check in the Python code itself to make sure that the user is running Python 3 instead of 2 and raise a meaningful exception if the wrong version is used. Here's an example: http://sweetme.at/2013/10/21/how-to-detect-python-2-vs-3-in-your-python-script/. This isn't "smart", however, since it requires the user to read the error message and change their command manually.

Comment: You can try adding `#!/usr/bin/env python3` to the first line of your file, make the file executable, and have them run the file directly.

Comment: Thank you to everyone who helped!

Answer (score 2):

Under Python 2, you can use `raw_input` instead of `input` to prevent Python from interpreting the user input as Python code.

However, since Python 2 is deprecated, I **strongly recommend against using it**<sup>1</sup>. Use Python 3 instead, where `input` works as expected.

---

<sup>1</sup> Except of course to maintain legacy products. But that doesn’t seem relevant here.